# Assertion failed in chrome extension and duplication

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**In background.js:**

```
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(changeInfo.status === "loading") {
    if (tab.url.indexOf('google.com') > -1 || tab.url.indexOf('amazon.com') > -1) {
     chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
}
}
};
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){

if (tab.url.indexOf('google.com') > -1){

    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {google_go: "go"});
    });

    chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://facebook.com", "active":true});
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
            console.assert(port.name == "facebook_chanel");
            port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
              if (msg.facebook_go == "go")
                port.postMessage(request);
            });
          });
        });
}
```

**In facebook.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "facebook_chanel"});
    port.postMessage({facebook_go: "go"});
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {

        console.log(msg);

    });

});
```

I go too google. Press on **pageAction**, I see tab with facebook, see one **Object** in console. In `html/background.html` console (Chrome) I see the error `Assertion failed:` in

```
console.assert(port.name == "facebook_chanel");
```

I go to google again, press **pageAction**, and I see at new facebook page one old and 2 new **Objects**.

How to fix it? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

in **background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://facebook.com", "active":true}, function(tab){
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
                chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tab) {
                  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id, request);
                });

        });
    });
```

in **facebook.js**:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(request);
  });
```

Its right way? But I have clear console, whats wrong?

Comment: Why don't you do `console.log(port.name)` to see if it is really `facebook_chanel`?

Comment: `console.log(port.name)` returns `facebook_chanel`. I use code from here http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html (Long-lived connections)

Comment: Just comment that `assert` statement and try

Comment: no errors but Object duplicates stayed

Comment: I press one time pageAction - in `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`  I have 1 object. 2 times - 2 objects. 3 - 3, etc. I have no idea, how to fix it.

Comment: Every time the page action is clicked, you add a new listener for port connections. That is why you get 2 objects the 2nd time, 3 objects the 3rd etc. Regarding how to fix it: What exactly is supposed to happen ? And why do you need persistent ports ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem I parsing some information from google pages and post it in facebook. About ports - I read it in docs, all extension works in that way.

Comment: @tim: What are "all extensions" that work that way ? I also see the notifications API in the docs - it doesn't mean my extension has to use it. Why do you need ports and not single message passing. Please, give some context. Hiw exactly is your extension going to work ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem I say `all extension`, I mean `all my extension`. For example, I whant to copy one text from first site(for example, google) to another site (facebook). On google site I press PageAction, background.html send message to google.js to parse the information. When background has request, its send it to facebook.js, so I can add the information in text form.

Comment: I sounds like you rather needs `chrome.runtime.sendMessage/onMessage` instead of persistent ports, snce you want it to be a one-time communication each time the page-action is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still not very clear what you are trying to achieve and why you chose to use porsistent ports (instead of single messaging) and page-actions, but from what I did understand, context-menus could be a better/cleaner approach.

So, below is the source code of a sample extension that registers a context-menu for when some text is selected (i.e. select/highlight some text and right click) and then opens an Facebook tab and sends the selected text for further processing (by the FB tab's content script).

If you still need a page-action instead of a context-menu, change the code like this:

1. Add listener for `chrome.pageAction.onClicked` in background-page.
2. Inject some code into the original tab (e.g. `google.com`) to retrieve ad return the current selection (using `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`).
3. Handle the acquired selected text as demonstrated in the code below.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",
    "offline_enabled": false,

    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":    ["*://*.facebook.com/"],
        "js":         ["content.js"],
        "run_at":     "document_end",
        "all_frames": false
    }],

    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus"
    ]
}
```

**content.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {

    /* Input validation */
    if (!msg.source || !msg.text) {
        console.error('Bad message format: ', msg);
        return;
    }

    /* Handle the selected text */
    switch (msg.source) {
    case 'Amazon':
    case 'Google':
        alert('Selected on ' + msg.source + ':\n' + msg.text);
        break;
    default:
        alert('Unknown source: ' + msg.source);
        break;
    }

});
```

**background.js:**

```
var contextMenuID = 'copyToFB';
var googleRegex = /^https?:\/\/(?:[^\.]+\.)?google\..+/;
var amazonRegex = /^https?:\/\/(?:[^\.]+\.)?amazon\..+/;

/* `onUpdated` listener factory (for when FB has loaded) */
var listenerFactory = function(trgTabID, msgSrc, selectedText) {
    return function(tabId, info, tab) {
        if ((trgTabID === tabId) && (info.status === 'complete')) {
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(arguments.callee);
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(trgTabID, {
                source: msgSrc,
                text: selectedText
            });
        }
    }
};

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    type:     'normal',
    id:       contextMenuID,
    title:    'Copy to Facebook',
    contexts: ['selection'],
    // For some reason documentsUrlPatterns 
    // does not seem to work (at least on Windows).
    // Theoratically, you should be able to limit the 
    // context-menu on specific sites only
    //documentUrlPatterns: [
        //'*://*.google.*/*',
        //'*://*.amazon.*/*'
    //],
    enabled:  true
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    console.log('Context menu clicked: ', info.menuItemId);
    if (info.menuItemId === contextMenuID) {
        var selectedText = info.selectionText;
        console.log('Selected text: ', selectedText);
        if (!selectedText) {
            alert('Nothing to copy to Facebook !');
            return;
        }

        var url = info.frameUrl ? info.frameUrl : info.pageUrl;
        if (googleRegex.test(url)) {
            console.log('Google.com URL: ', url);

            /* Handle text selected on `google.com` */
            chrome.tabs.create({
                url: 'http://facebook.com/',
                active: true
            }, function(tab) {
                chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
                        listenerFactory(tab.id, 'Google', selectedText));
            });
        } else if (amazonRegex.test(url)) {
            console.log('Amazon.com URL: ', url);

            /* Handle text selected on `amazon.com` */
            chrome.tabs.create({
                url: 'http://facebook.com/',
                active: true
            }, function(tab) {
                chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
                        listenerFactory(tab.id, 'Amazon', selectedText));
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Non-matching URL: ', url);
        }
    }
});
```

---

Final notes:

- Because `documentUrlPatterns` does not seem to work (at least on Windows), the context-menu is shown on every page (when you select some text). You could add extra listeners (e.g. for `chrome.tabs.onActivated` etc) to remove or disable the context menu when the user is not on one of the permitted URLs.
- It might be a good idea to keep track of an ope FB tab and not create a new one every time. (Or you could also look for an already opened (e.g. by the user) FB tab.)

Comment: sorry, but I dont need any context-menus. All information parsing with help google.js, in background I can see request, that I send from google.js, then I send it to facebook.js, that can add request in the page. But in facebook.js console is clear, its very strange, I have no idea why.